# Delete values with the same foreign key

Tags: mysql

Below I have a very basic example of a table named `person` where the values have a foreign key named `acad_id`. I am trying to perform a delete a query and only delete the values that have `acad_id` value of `15`. Sorry for the simple question, I am not sure if it is necessary to specify all the fields that needed to be delete.

Before delete query

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | acad_id |  Name   |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  |      15 | James   |
| 2  |      15 | Cynthia |
| 3  |       8 | Peter   |
+----+---------+---------+
```

After delete query

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | acad_id |  Name   |
+----+---------+---------+
| 3  |       8 | Peter   |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: No you do not have to specify the fields.  You are simply deleting all rows in the table that meet the condition.

Comment: really... SQL is not that hard to learn... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple where statement combine with DELETE FROM

```
DELETE FROM person WHERE acad_id = 15
```

This query delete all record matching acad_id = 15. I advise you to create a back up of your table before running a delete statement. It is also nice to run the matching select to make sure that you delete only records you really want to. In this case the select statement will be:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE acad_id = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from person where acad_id = 15
```

Could you seriously not find any examples of this?

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt sure if I had to specify each field to delete.